# Graphics3D display issue

Tags: graphics3d, windows

I have a display issue using Graphics3D. I would like to simply display an array of similar cuboids, all having the same size, distributed in the y-direction. When I use Graphics3D to display the cuboids, the bottom cuboids look fine but the top ones are shrinked on the edge.

Here is a simple code of my problem :

```
numberOfLines = 30;
widthLine = .001;
spaceBetweenLines = .001;

horizontalLines = 
  Table[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0 - widthLine, widthLine}] /. {x_, y_,z_} -> {x, y - n*(widthLine + spaceBetweenLines), z}}, {n, 0, numberOfLines}];
verticalLine = 
  Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}, {1 + widthLine, -(numberOfLines+ 1)*(widthLine + spaceBetweenLines),widthLine}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], horizontalLines, verticalLine}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

For visual inspection I have added a vertical line on the side so it's easier to see the display issue. All the horizontal lines should touch the vertical side on the right (like the first 6). Zooming on the the right edge we see the issue :
[image]

It seems that the issue is more visible when the dimensions of the lines are small. Is there a parameter to adjust that would change this behavior?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: On version 13.0.1 the graphics is displayed correctly.

Comment: Oh OK, I am using version "13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" and have the issue described.

Comment: Problem is reproducible on 13.3.0 for Windows

Comment: The issue is not present in `13.2.1` on a mac. I am wondering if this is related to the OS. Perhaps someone with Linux could try? I have tentatively added the `windows` tag

Comment: Does the `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"` option correct the problem?

Comment: @creidhne, unfortunately the problem persists using this option.